# Could not find grapher 'qwingraph.exe' ida

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

When looking for xrefs to a string in memory, I keep getting the following error:
[image]

Found no sources on it online, any direction on what might be the cause & how to fix?

Note: I use ida freeware 7.0, Windows 10

Comment: Do you have `qwingraph.exe` file in your IDA home directory?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with IDA Freeware 7.0. Reinstallation did nothing.

Downloading qwingraph from an external source fixed it for me.
You can either [compile it yourself from the official source](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/qwingraph_src.zip) or [download an executable file from a repository](https://github.com/x64dbg/testplugin/releases/tag/Wingraph/).

Once you have the executable (qwingraph.exe), place it in your IDA home directory (e. g. C:\Program Files\IDA Freeware 7.0).

Note: If qwingraph.exe is downloaded from the [repository](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/freefiles/qwingraph_src.zip) linked above, the QtCore4 and QtGui4 dlls (which can be found in the same repository) might also be mandatory. That is so because the executable uses Qt4, and recent versions of IDA Freeware use Qt5, thus causing an incompatibility.

Comment: Downloading `qwingraph.rar` from the repo and placing the 3 extracted files into my IDA home directory worked, thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

Is happening to me as well.  Fresh install, no qwingraph.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall IDA Freeware 7.0, you should have qwingraph.exe in your IDA Freeware directory.